# How can i get json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get an array from json but i don't know how to get bookTitle and url.
How can i read this items in the arrays ?

```
$data = file_get_contents('C:\Users\rsanchro\Desktop\ftp brasil4-9-2015\moderna_plus-historia\MPCH-C05-P1-1.0.1-ZIP-PT\resource.json');
$datos = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($datos);die;

Results:
    Array
    (
        [topBarColor] => #000000
        [bookId] => 2aef55bf3a9dec377b4f16a8048c7f84
        [bookTitle] => HistÃ³ria
        [unitId] => MPCH-C05-P1
        [unitTitle] => 108-127-MPCH-C05-P1-M
        [unitResources] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => 03
                        [url] => resources/mphis_c06av_escultura_ontem.mp4
                        [urlToShowInsideUnit] => #/compId/id0a33b2a0471e0f444bc0a88b5bb55714
                        [title] => A escultura ontem e hoje
                        [page] => 123
                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
        print_r(utf8_decode($datos['bookTitle']));
        if(is_array($datos['unitResources']) && count($datos['unitResources']) > 0){
            foreach($datos['unitResources'] as $key => $value){
                print_r($value['url']);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are having only single data use the following

```
$bookTitle=$datos['bookTitle'];
$url=$datos['unitResources'][0]['url'];
```

If you have more than one data in the array then use the following

```
foreach($datos as $dato){
  $bookTitle=$dato['bookTitle'];
  $urls=array();
  foreach($datos['unitResources'] as $url){
    $urls[]=$url['url'];
  }
  echo '<br>Book Title :'.$bookTitle;
  echo '<br>urls :';
  foreach($urls as $url){
    echo $url.'<br>';
  }
}
```

For your example array which you mentioned. you can use the first method.
but since you are working with array better use the 2nd method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo  "Title:".$datos['bookTitle']; //To print book title

    //To print url
    if(is_array($datos['unitResources']) && count($datos['unitResources']) > 0){
                foreach($datos['unitResources'] as $key => $value){
                    echo "URL:".$value['url'] ;
                }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend taking a look at the jsonselect library. It provides an intuitive selection syntax that is modeled after CSS selector syntax.

JSON Select project site:
http://jsonselect.org/#overview

PHP implementation:
https://github.com/observu/JSONselect-php